# Integrating Annyang.js speech recogniton with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, speech-recognition

I'm attempting to integrate [Annyang.js](http://www.annyangjs.com/) and [Angular.js](http://www.angularjs.com/).

I'm trying to make the result of Annyang.js bind (Angular style) with the DOM. Some ideas might be to use angular services like $watch, $apply, $digest, or to create a directive/factory/provider??? I'm at a loss. Help would be appreciated.

So far, it understands commands within the VoiceCtrl scope but it does not bind to $scope.said

Javascript:

```
var SpeechApp = angular.module('SpeechApp', []);

function VoiceCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.said='';

  $scope.helloWorld = function() {
    $scope.said = "Hello world!";
  }

  $scope.commands = {
    'hello (world)': $scope.helloWorld,
  };

  annyang.debug();
  annyang.init($scope.commands);
  annyang.start();
}
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="Voice" ng-controller="VoiceCtrl">
    <p>{{said}}</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing a `scope.$apply()`. This is needed to allow angular to update all of your bindings as annyang.js is going to be working outside of angular context.

Try replacing your command with

```
'Hello (world)': function() {
    $scope.$apply($scope.helloWorld);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you call the module "SpeechApp" in you JS and ng-app="Voice" in your HTML.

Suggest this HTML instead:

```
  <body ng-app="SpeechApp">
    <div ng-controller="VoiceCtrl">
      <p>Hi: {{said}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QIWwhS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [AngularJS Speech Recognition with annyang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ds5tm-6Nc9g)